# Firebase .constant Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a constant set up in my app.js file, and I've injected it into my controller (main.js), but it doesn't seem to want to work:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('fireApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'firebase'
])
.constant('FBURL', 'https://outcomes.firebaseio.com/')
...
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('fireApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'firebase'
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, $firebase, FBURL) {
...
}
```

Now I do question why I've got two modules set up. Is there a way around this? I'd like to keep my module, config and constant in my (app.js) file. How can I inject that `.constant('FBURL')` from my (app.js) file to my (main.js) file?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: what errors are you getting at the moment?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FBURLProvider <- FBURL <- MainCtrl`

Comment: Does your `main.js` look exactly like you've shown? Including the `var app...` part?

Comment: Yes, except there's an `app.config()` and `app.factory()`, which I've left out of the code above. Strangely enough, if I add the `app.constant('FBURL', 'https://***.firebaseio.com/');` to the main.js file, it works just fine. Just doesn't seem to work when tacked onto the app.js file.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the app variable again. I will give an example below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there are different ways of doing this but I tend to structure my Angularjs app like so:

In the `app.js` file

```
angular
  .module('fireApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'firebase'

  ])

  .constant('FBURL', 'https://outcomes.firebaseio.com/')
```

and in the `/controllers/main.js` I have:

```
angular.module('fireApp')
  .controller('myController', ['$scope','FBURL', function($scope,FBURL) {

  }])
```

This should solve your problem. Note that I have't injected all the same things as you so you will need to add these.

Comment: Thank you! This works great now. I understand this structure a bit more now.